# how to animate a custom-element of a dom-repeat in polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm trying to apply a cascaded-animation on a dom-repeat elements. when the element inside the repeat element is a paper-card or paper-material everything is fine but replacing it with a custom element removes the animation effect.
I added the animatable behavior to the element, but it doesn't work.

here is my list

```
<dom-module id="list-view">

    <template>

        <template id="list" is="dom-repeat" items={{records}} on-dom-change="_renderRepeat">
            <task-element
                title="{{item.title}}"
                duration="{{item.duration}}"
                project="{{item.project}}"
                client="{{item.client}}"
                id="{{item.id}}"
                on-editing="onEditRecord"
                on-delete="onDeleteRecord"
                on-update="onUpdateRecord"
            ></task-element>
        </template>
    </template>
<script src="list-view.js"></script>
```

and the _renderRepeat function:

```
    _renderRepeat: function () {
        this.paperCard = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('task-element');
        this.animationConfig['entry'].push({
            name: 'cascaded-animation',
            animation: 'transform-animation',
            transformFrom: 'translateY(100vh)',
            nodes: this.paperCard
        });

        this.playAnimation('entry');
    }
```

the task-element has "Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior" behavior.
I think something must be inherited from base paper-element which i don't know what it is.

Thank you

Comment: can you setup a JSBIN with the minimal to reproduce?

Comment: I guess i've found the reason, but i don't know how to fix it. In my custom element i used paper-card and i've changed the display of paper card to 'block', when i remove it animation runs just fine.

Comment: here is the bin: http://jsbin.com/nuziho/edit?html,output when you comment out the display: 'block' in task-element it works fine. but i need it to be block

Comment: I got your example to work by adding css to the `task-element`'s host so that it's `:host{ display: block;}` look http://jsbin.com/mohegacoxa/edit?html,output

Comment: thank you, can you tell me the reason?